# How to combine Bash's process substitution with HERE-document?

Tags: bash, process-substitution, here-document

In Bash version 4.2.47(1)-release when I try to catenate formatted text that comes from a HERE-dcoument like so:

```
cat <(fmt --width=10 <<FOOBAR
(I want the surrounding parentheses to be part of the HERE-document)
(Even the preceding unbalanced parenthesis should be part of it.
FOOBAR
) # I want this paranthesis to end the process substitution.
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: bad substitution: no closing `)' in <(fmt --width=10 <<FOOBAR
(I want the surrounding parentheses to be part of the HERE-document)
(Even the preceding unbalanced parenthesis should be part of it.
FOOBAR
)
```

Also I do not want to quote the HERE-document, i.e. write `<'FOOBAR'`, because I still want to have variables being substituted within it.

Comment: Do you really need the `cat` call? Why not leave it at calling `fmt`?

Comment: I must admit it is a contrived example. My actual needs are more complex than that.

Comment: It is interesting that when you replace `(Even` with `"(Even"` it works. It is same for `\(Even`. Looks like a parsing bug. Bash is still in a context were it is looking for braces while also in the context of reading the here doc and both contexts contradict each other.

Comment: This is fixed in `bash` 4.3, incidentally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process substitution is roughly equivalent to this.

#### Example - mechanics of process substitution

*Step #1 - make a fifo, output to it*

```
$ mkfifo /var/tmp/fifo1
$ fmt --width=10 <<<"$(seq 10)" > /var/tmp/fifo1 &
[1] 5492
```

*Step #2 - read the fifo*

```
$ cat /var/tmp/fifo1
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10
[1]+  Done                    fmt --width=10 <<< "$(seq 10)" > /var/tmp/fifo1
```

The use of parens within the HEREDOC also seems OK:

#### Example - just using a FIFO

*Step #1 - output to FIFO*

```
$ fmt --width=10 <<FOO > /var/tmp/fifo1 &
(one)
(two
FOO
[1] 10628
```

*Step #2 - read contents of FIFO*

```
$ cat /var/tmp/fifo1
(one)
(two
```

The trouble, I believe you're running into is that the process substitution, `<(...)`, doesn't seem to care for the nesting of parens within it.

#### Example - process sub + HEREDOC don't work

```
$ cat <(fmt --width=10 <<FOO
(one)
(two
FOO
)
bash: bad substitution: no closing `)' in <(fmt --width=10 <<FOO
(one)
(two
FOO
)
$
```

Escaping the parens seems to appease it, a little:

#### Example - escaping parens

```
$ cat <(fmt --width=10 <<FOO                 
\(one\)
\(two
FOO
)
\(one\)
\(two
```

But doesn't really give you what you want. Making the parens balanced also seems  to appease it:

#### Example - balancing parens

```
$ cat <(fmt --width=10 <<FOO
(one)
(two)
FOO
)
(one)
(two)
```

Whenever I have complex strings, such as this to contend with in Bash, I almost always will construct them first, storing them in a variable, and then use them via the variable, rather than try and craft some tricky one liner that ends up being fragile.

#### Example - use a variable

```
$ var=$(fmt --width=10 <<FOO
(one)
(two
FOO
)
```

Then to print it:

```
$ echo "$var"
(one)
(two
```

#### References

- [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)
- [How can I write a here doc to a file in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script)
- [Using Named Pipes and Process Substitution](https://vincebuffalo.com/blog/2013/08/08/using-names-pipes-and-process-substitution-in-bioinformatics.html)
- [Closing Brackets in Here Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466713/closing-brackets-in-here-documents)

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, and as you realize that this is a contrived example (and thus that the correct solution is to use `cat |` or actually, no `cat` at all in this case), I'll just post my answer for the general case. I would solve it by putting it in a function and using that instead.

```
fmt-func() {
    fmt --width=10 <<FOOBAR
(I want the surrounding parentheses to be part of the HERE-document)
(Even the preceding unbalanced parenthesis should be part of it.
FOOBAR
}
```

and then use that

```
cat <(fmt-func)
```

Comment: This is a great solution to supplying scripts as files to interpreters (`awk`, `grep`, `node`, `python`, etc.) so that they can accept stdin for processing. It is also great for passing configs to commands like `aws` with the `--cli-input-json` flag.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, a way to include short interpreter scripts in my bash scripts.  I simply used `cat <<EOF` inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a workaround. Pipe `fmt` to `cat` instead of using process substitution

```
fmt --width=10 <<FOOBAR | cat 
(I want the surrounding parentheses to be part of the HERE-document)
(Even the preceding unbalanced parenthesis should be part of it.
FOOBAR
```

Comment: I tried your "workaround" and it would work for me. Thanks. But still I want to grasp why my combination of a HERE-document nested inside a process substitution does not work. Have you got an answer?

Comment: @TimFriske, I'm going to have to defer that one to one of the `bash` wizards on this site. My knowledge of bash parser internals is limited to say the least